# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito Ayuda
Me aparece este error, aun cuando He seguido soluciones de este foro, no se muestra la consulta que deseo realizar, Requiero Que me haga la consulta.
He intentado En cambiar algunas variables, Pero ni me han resultado. Aca esta una parte del codigo

`El dashboard es de Bootstrap 4`

```
<?php $link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sure") or die ("No se ha podido realizar la conexión"); ?>
                  <tbody>
                  
                    <?php

                      $query="SELECT Al.Id, Al.Nombre, Al.Apellido_Paterno, Al.Apellido_Materno, Al.Fecha_de_Nacimiento, Al.Sexo, Al.Direccion, Al.Telefono, Al.Correo_Electronico,
                              Per.Tipo, Per.Grado,
                          FROM alumnos Al
                          INNER JOIN periodo Per ON Al.Id_Periodo = Per.Id_Periodo";
                      $consulta=$link->query($query);
                      while ($registroalumnos=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                          echo"<tr>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Id"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Nombre"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Apellido_Paterno"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Apellido_Materno"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Fecha_de_Nacimiento"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Sexo"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Direccion"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Telefono"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Correo_Electronico"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Tipo"]."</td>
                          <td>".$registroalumnos["Grado"]."</td>
                          </tr>";
                        }


                    ?>
```

Comment: Tienes una coma de más antes del `FROM`, exactamente aquí `Per.Grado,`

Comment: Puedes poner en que linea te lo marca

Comment: Es en la linea 280 (la parte del codigo desde <?php es desde la linea 273 )

Comment: @Brand Bruno Levet se refiere a la parte del codigo que te muestra ese error, no el número de la línea, por cierto, ¿al quitar la coma que te menciono, el error persiste?

Comment: @JosueArriola Si es correcto a eso me referia

Comment: Si, Aun perciste. Y me aparece la Siguiente Información:                         Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sure\Alumnos.php on line 280
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sure\Alumnos.php on line 280
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.4029 421536 {main}( ) ...\Alumnos.php:0

Comment: Para que comprendas un poco mas este error se debe a que intentas usar una variable que retorna True o False y quieres convertirla en un array

Comment: Tambien elimina ese `FETCH ASSOC`, la funcion `fetch( )` ya convierte a array

Comment: En el código estás mezclando `mysqli` con `PDO` y eso no es posible. Dinos qué API estás usando de esas dos.

Comment: Aun Persiste el error, Ya elimine la variable ```FETCH_ASSOC```  y convertí la función ```fetch()``` a ```fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))```

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy ocupando MySqli

Comment: @kllmp Me aparece este error ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sure\Alumnos.php on line 280
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sure\Alumnos.php on line 280
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.4040 421536 {main}( ) ...\Alumnos.php:0

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error ocurre cuando intentas leer resultados sobre un booleano. Generalmente una consulta debería devolver un conjunto de resultados que se pueda leer, pero cuando la consulta falla por algún motivo devuelve `false`, de ahí el error: *`Call to a member function fetch() on bool`*

Para evitar eso, te aconsejo que escribas un programa controlado y que seas lo más pesimista posible cuando programes. Sí sí, pesimista. Es decir, piensa que todo, sí todo, puede salir mal y que tú estás ahí para controlar y responder cuando algo salga mal. Esa es una tarea fundamental de un programador. Lo digo porque generalmente se enseña a programar pensando que todo es color de rosa. El control de errores es deficiente en la mayoría de código que veo por ahí.

Aquí te dejo un código robusto, que te dirá lo que haya ocurrido y podrás en consecuencia resolver cualquier problema. En cuanto al usuario, este código no lo dejará en el limbo si algo falla, sino que le dirá que algo, y qué, ha fallado.

Lo he comentado abundantemente, de modo que entiendas cada cosa en su sitio.

```
<?php
    #Usaremos estilo orientado a objetos en todo 
    $link=new mysqli("localhost","root","","sure");
    
    #Se recomienda evitar die(), es para programadores vagos
    #que no quieren controlar su código, verificamos y controlamos todo
    #que para eso es que se programa, no para delegar en die
    #1ª verificación: ¿Hay conexión
    if (!$link)
    {
        #Si no hay conexión lo guardamos en una variable
        #Ojo, esta variable nos sirve para controlar el código
        $mData="No se ha podido realizar la conexión";
    } else {
        #Si hay conexión pasamos a la consulta
        $query="SELECT Al.Id, Al.Nombre, Al.Apellido_Paterno, Al.Apellido_Materno, Al.Fecha_de_Nacimiento, Al.Sexo,                     Al.Direccion, Al.Telefono, Al.Correo_Electronico,Per.Tipo, Per.Grado,
                FROM alumnos Al
                    INNER JOIN periodo Per ON Al.Id_Periodo = Per.Id_Periodo";
        #2ª verificación: ¿Hubo error en la consulta?            
        if(!$rs=$link->query($query)) 
        {
            $mData="Error en la consulta.";
        } else {
            #3ª verificación: ¿Trae filas las consulta?
            if ($rs->num_rows === 0) 
            {
                #Si no trae filas, lo informamos
                $mData="No se encontraron filas";
            } else {
                #Si trae filas, leemos los datos
                #Nótese que sólo aquí crearemos el tbody
                #OJO: supongo que en otra parte lo agregarás a un table
                $mData="<tbody>";
                #El método proppio para la lectura asociativa es fetch_assoc()
                 while ($row=$rs->fetch_assoc())
                 {

                    #Varias cosas aquí:
                    #1. He optado por una variable corta y más descriptiva $row
                    #   no tiene sentido una variable extra larga aquí
                    #2. Dado que usaremos una cadena completa rodeada por comillas "
                    #   al inicio y al final, podemos suprimir las comillas de nombres de clave
                    #   y las concatenaciones, quedando el código más simple y más claro                     
                    $mData.="<tr>
                    <td>$row[Id]</td>
                    <td>$row[Nombre]</td>
                    <td>$row[Apellido_Paterno]</td>
                    <td>$row[Apellido_Materno]</td>
                    <td>$row[Fecha_de_Nacimiento]</td>
                    <td>$row[Sexo]</td>
                    <td>$row[Direccion]</td>
                    <td>$row[Telefono]</td>
                    <td>$row[Correo_Electronico]</td>
                    <td>$row[Tipo]</td>
                    <td>$row[Grado]</td>
                    </tr>";
                }
                #Cerramos el tbody fuera del while
                $mData.="</tbody>";
            }
        }
    }
    #Aquí se imprimirá lo que haya ocurrido
    echo $mData;                    
?>
```

Comment: 1-Ya no me dio el problema de error pero no me hizo la lectura de las tablas. 2-Gracias por ayudarme en solucionar el error. 3-La parte de la tabla, Va pegada en el cuerpo de la misma